# How to get properties or method?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When we replaced the image path on the canvas,there is some method can use,such as
`fabric.util.loadImage` or `fabric.Image.fromURL(function(){})....`

I want to change `src` of the image on the group when I click the button,I use `setSrc(imagePath)` method,but it can't use.

After that,I guess there could be the image loaded problem.
I replaced the method `fabric.Image.fromURL(function(){})` as the above and delete the browser cache ,no reply.

Finally,I modify the image to the Circle,and set the fill after.
I use the `setFill()` to change the color,it can't,neither.
Howerer,I use the `set("fill","red")`,it ran smoothly.
I was confused,did those method outdated? 
Or I made the mistake somewhere?
It's the demo from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/ang58fcL/23/).

I saw the question on

```
 https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1762
```

And I want to know where can get properties,because I saw the tutorial page of the official website,
It shows the opacity,width,height.....etc.

```
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html
```

Are the properties show there?
And how can I modify the image path to achieve the result we want?

Thanks.